# Invoking Apache-FOP from C++

Tags: c++, java-native-interface, xsl-fo, apache-fop

Has anyone experience or had problems implementing a JNI wrapper for apache FOP?

Bonus points:
Any other options for processing xsl-fo  from C++?

Answer (score 0):

well, the obious way is to

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>

int runFop(const char* params) {

     // put the real path here
     const char* FOP_CMD = "fop.bat";

     std::string cmd(FOP_CMD);
     cmd += " ";
     cmd += params;

     return system(cmd.c_str());
}
```

Comment: Nice, but hardly answer my plroblem

Comment: why not? do you want the fop created in-memory-only?

Answer (score 0):

I would be interested in this answer as well, because I was looking for the same thing a couple years ago, and eventually just used the Java FOP which was not ideal for our case since we were using it from a C++ application.

Answer (score 0):

I do that for C# not for C.
I generate proxies to wrap fop classes, so it looks like original fop example, [but it's not Java](http://code.google.com/p/jni4net/source/browse/trunk/content/samples/fop/csharp/Program.cs). The tool I use is [jni4net](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jace/) I created.

For you [Jace](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jace/) would be good choice I think.

Answer (score 0):

We initially used fop as our rendering engine but found it had some size limitiations.  We ended up purchasing a third-party product from Ecrion - XF Rendering Service.  Yeah I know, its not open source, its not free, but it is a very good product that we have used for several years now with very good results.